# How can I plot a one day chart for each day in R from my 1 year of minute data and then export the plots?

Tags: r, csv, plot, xts, quantmod

In R,

I have 1 year of csv timeseries data in format DateTime and Close. I want to plot 1 day graphs of each day and then export them, ideally having the file name be the date of the graph.

The steps in this link http://www.r-bloggers.com/automatically-save-your-plots-to-a-folder/ are very helpful and are what I will use, but I need help figuring out how to automate the plotting of one day graphs first.

Currently using chart_Series to chart and then zoom_Chart to focus on the dates I want, and then manually exporting.

I am doing

```
spxxts <- xts(spx$Close, order.by = spx$DateTime)
chart_Series(spxxts)
```

and then

```
zoom_Chart("2007-04-30")
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: So, what specifically is your question? Is there a problem with the code you have tried (if so, what is it)? Is it purely that you need to know how to write a loop over the dates? A reproducible example would be fantastic.

Comment: You can utilize the `subset=` argument of `chart_Series()` so that you don't have to use `zoom_Chart()`.  To save the charts to disk, you could use the `png()` function then `chart_Series()` then `dev.off()`, or you could use `dev.copy()`

Comment: Yes I want to know how to write a loop, that would do the subset function and then also save the charts to disk via the functions outlined above^.

Comment: How could I write a function that would do subset= and then save each subsequent day?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will loop through the dates in your data and save the charts via: `saveChart()` by `quantmod` but you can change it to whatever you use to save charts:

```
# Required data
spxxts <- xts(spx$Close, order.by = spx$DateTime)

# Creates a Vector of all the ACTUAL days in your data (trading days)
INDX <- unique(as.Date(index(spxxts))) 


# Loop
for(ii in 1:length(INDX)){

  # plot:
  chart_Series(spxxts[paste(INDX[ii])], name=paste0(",INDX[ii]),"")

  # save:
  saveChart("jpeg")

}
```

the `saveChart` function will use the name of the chart & make that the name of the .jpeg and save it to your working directory... as requested the name of the chart is the trading date

Comment: when i run it it gives this error message?







Error: unexpected string constant in:
"                                                     # save:
                                                     saveChart(""
                                                  
>  }
Error: unexpected '}' in " }"

Comment: also it gives unexpected token error for the end parentheses in this

INDX[ii]),"")